# How to filter an action inside class in MemberPress plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying remove the following:

```
$wp_user = wp_signon(
    array(
        'user_login' => $mepr_screenname,
        'user_password' => $mepr_user_password,
    ),
    MeprUtils::is_ssl()
);
```

from function `process_reset_password_form()` using a filter function in the child theme but not getting any way.

Here is the complete code https://github.com/wp-premium/memberpress-business/blob/master/app/controllers/MeprLoginCtrl.php

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like the function where this is located is `process_login_form`, and without `wp_signon` your users won't login when processing the login form. Why do you need to remove this?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no filter or action hook nearby that will allow you to simply change this. Not without having to re-implement an enormous chunk of the plugin.

Comment: this function actually, automatically logged user in after resetting password. i am trying to redirect to login page instead of auto logged in